# Nextjs/React expand box (accordion) animation failed with tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, tailwind-css

I am trying to make animation for an expandable box (accordion).

This is what I want to achieve: the child component is by default set as `display:none`. When I hover my mouse to its parent component, the child is shown, and the width/height of the parent is adjusted accordingly.

However the animation is **not** working

Here is a minimal reproduction:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex w-[50vw] p-10 items-center justify-center">
      <div className="border-black group border-2 transition-all min-w-5 min-h-5 w-auto h-auto bg-red-300">
        <div className="hidden w-20 group-hover:block bg-gray-200">
          placeholder
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

I noticed that the animation would work if i were to set the size of the parent manually like this:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex w-[50vw] p-10 items-center justify-center">
      <div className="border-black group border-2 transition-all w-5 h-5 hover:w-10 hover:h-10 bg-red-300">
        <div className="hidden w-20 group-hover:block bg-gray-200">
          placeholder
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

But this is not desired: as we have to place magic numbers for parent's size.

Is it possible to let the first version of my code to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitioning an element from `display:none` to `block` is rather tricky, simply because "a block element cannot be partly displayed". The browser has no way of computing a transition there.

I'd suggest trying a different approach, either using an external library (Framer-motion, gsap) or a follow the max-height approach suggested in @wongjn 's comment.

Here's a [codepen with a tailwind solution](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/dyGLzgY?editors=1000) using the max-height approach.

Hope this helps!